# Django restframework send post data is broken from test APIClient

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

`request.data.get('answers_ids')` returned `str '2'` instead of `array ['1', '2']` when sent from APIClient data. But when I send data from rest framework web-gui all works.

Using:

- django == 1.10.4
- djangorestframework == 3.5.3

tests.py:

```
class ApiCompletePoll(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.user = User.objects.create(
            username='123',
            password='123',
            email='123@123.ru'
        )
        self.client = APIClient()
        self.client.credentials(
             HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token ' + self.user.auth_token.key
        )

    def test_complete_poll(self):
        data = {'poll_id': 1, 'answers_ids': [1, 2]}     # SENT DATA
        self.client.post(reverse('complete-poll'), data)
        self.assertTrue(
            CompletedPoll.objects.filter(
                user=self.user, poll__id=data['poll_id']
            )
        )
```

views.py:

```
@api_view(http_method_names=['post', ])
def update_or_create_user_answers(request):
    user = request.user
    poll_id = request.data.get('poll_id', 0)
    answers_ids = request.data.get('answers_ids', [])

    print(list(request.data.items()), request.data, answers_ids)    # GETTING DATA
```

Output:

```
[('answers_ids', '2'), ('poll_id', '1')] 
<QueryDict: {'answers_ids': ['1', '2'], 'poll_id': ['1']}> 
2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve a list of values for the passed key in a `QueryDict` you need to use the `.getlist()` method:

```
answers_ids = request.data.getlist('answers_ids', [])
```

This should output: `['1', '2']`